# Why does the modal verb come at the end?

Tags: sentence-structure

I wonder why the modal verb comes at the end here?

> ..., die die Produktivität des Programmierers erhöhen **soll**.

Comment: Your citation seems to be incomplete. Can you quote the complete sentence, please?

Comment: I don't understand the somewhat reflexive close-votes. True, it is not a very well asked question, but a competent speaker of german will know what the questioner wants to know. So voting to close because of _it is unclear what you are asking_ is somewhat fogeyish in my humble opinion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is because the snippet you posted is a dependent clause. It explains something in the main clause. Dependent clauses have their conjugated verb in the last position in German.

> Agile Softwareentwicklung ist eine Methode, **die** die Produktivität des Programmierers erhöhen soll.

The first *die* isn't an article but a relative pronoun. Der/die/das often replaces the pretty clunky *welcher/welche/welches* relative pronoun.

Comment: +1, esp. for the (successful) effort of trying to understand what the questioner probably wanted to know instead of a somewhat knee-jerk approach to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has nothing to do with modal verbs. In any subordinate clause the verb is placed at the end.

On the site of the University of Michigan you [find](https://www.lsa.umich.edu/german/hmr/Grammatik/Relativsaetze/relative.html):

> **III. Where to position the verb in the relative clause**
>
> This is easy also: relative clauses are subordinate clauses. Consequently, the conjugated verb comes at the end of the relative clause.